# java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException issue with databindings

Tags: java, android, android-databinding

I have been observing the below crash on my android vitals with a very very high crash rate and cannot make out the reason for the same. Tried investigating for long time but could not reach a conclusion.

> 1. The stack trace gives no clue on what and where is going wrong.
> 2. I cannot reproduce the issue as I have no idea what workflow ion the app is causing this.
> 3. It is happening on all android versions for me.

It would be of great help if someone can give me a direction on what and how to investigate or if they have come across the similar issue and what was their approach to deal with this.

```
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: 
at android.databinding.b.b (b.java:277)
at android.databinding.a.removeOnPropertyChangedCallback (a.java:40)
at android.databinding.p$g.b (p.java:1139)
at android.databinding.p$g.b (p.java:1119)
at android.databinding.p$e.a (p.java:1099)
at android.databinding.p.g (p.java:390)
at android.databinding.p.finalize (p.java:397)
at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize (Daemons.java:217)
at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run (Daemons.java:200)
at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: The usual suspect is always things like looping on a set and removing items from that.....did you check that?

Comment: Are you using two-way data binding? If you you need to break out of the infinite update-read loop manually.

Comment: @VeneetReddy@Mohammad I believe you are suggesting the same thing. Thanks for a relevant direction, but is there a way I can know what are these data binding that are the culprit here? As the trace says nothing and have no logs too.

Comment: @VeneetReddy: I figured out, we are using two way data binding in our app. The problem I have is how to figure out which of the multiple properties I have data binding on is the culprit?